# Positivity of dual Curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

Let $M$ be a complex manifold or more generally an almorst complex manifold $(M,J)$
with $J \in End(TM)$ such that $J^2=-Id_{TM}$ (if $M$ is complex mfd then it's almost
complex al well with $J:=i \cdot id_{TM}$.

Assume $L \to M$ is a (holomorphic) line bundle on $M$ and
$\nabla^L: \Gamma(M,L) \to \Gamma(M T^*M \otimes L)$ is a connection on $L$.
Squaring $\nabla^E$ induces a curvature
$\Omega^E: \Gamma(M,L) \to \Gamma(M, \wedge^2 T^*M \otimes L)$.

It's a general fact that for arbitrary finite dimensional vector bundle
$E \to M$ a connection $\Omega^E$ uniquely determines a connection
$\Omega^{E^*}$ on the dual vector bundle $E^* \to M$
by: for every section $s \in \Gamma(M,E), f \in \Gamma(M,E^*)$
the induced connection $\Omega^{E^*}$ is determined by equation

$$(\Omega^{E^*} f)(s) = d(f(s))- f(\Omega^{E}s)$$

Let come back to line bundle $L$ (I not exclude that this holds more
generally for (holomorphic) vector bundles $E \to M$).
Assume $\Omega^L$ is negative. That means that at every point $x \in M$
and local section $s \in \Gamma(U, L)$ where $x \in U \subset_{open} M$
the curvature evaluated in $s_x=s(x) \in L_x$ as
$\Omega^L(-,J_x(-))(s_x) \in \wedge^2 T_x^*M$ is
*negative definite*. That means for arbitrary $X \in T_x M$ with $x \neq 0$ we have

$$\Omega^L(X,J_x(X))(s_x) <0$$

My question: If we assume that $\Omega^L$ is negative, is then
$\Omega^{L^*}$ positive? ie for all local $f \in \Gamma(U, L^*)$ holds
$\Omega^{L^*}(X,J_x(X))(s^*_x) >0$
for all $X \in T_x M$.

the question is motivated by the discussion in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3748449/c-1-j-is-riemannian-metric) around
the exercise to prove that $c_1(O(1))$ of the dual $O(1)$ of the tautological bundle
$O(-1)$ on $M= \mathbb{P^nC}$ is positive. Since $c_1$ not depends of choosen connection it suffice to find a connection on $O(1)$ with positive curvature.